# How to turn off has_one saving on set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-one

In Rails, I have a has_one association

```
class Car
  has_one :driver
end
```

When I do

```
driver = Driver.new
car.driver = driver
```

It tries to save my driver before I'm ready! I only want to save the driver when I call car.save

How can I have Rails 4.2.* change the order of saving?

Comment: Please describe the problem in more detail. Provide full controller, car and driver models.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it doesn't persist changes to database. You probably see it in memory.

```
car.driver = driver
car.driver == driver # true
car.reload
car.driver == dirver # false
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does persist. In fact it tries to persist it before I'm ready, and gives an error ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the new associated driver.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to trigger the save method without calling it.

**Unless** you have method in **Car model** that triggers it, like **autosave: true**